# find smallest number closest to an integer in an array excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic list of values in an excel worksheet.  I need to find a way to identify the lowest number in the array that is closest to a whole number.
example:
in one instance the list includes the following numbers:
1.56, 1.65, 1.71, 1.84, 1.94, 2.00, 2.06, 2.03, 2.22........2.95, 3.05, 3.81, 4.00 etc.
the number I want to find in this instance is 2.00.
Is there a function in Excel that I can use for this?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is your list always sorted ?

Comment: Why 2? also 4 is closest to a whole number.

Comment: If there are ties on the rounding (2 & 4), I think OP wants to find the lowest of them (2)

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

Formula for dif:

`=ABS(IFERROR(MID($A2,1,FIND(".",$A2,1)-1),$A2)-$A2)`

Formula for Min:

`=INDEX($A$2:$B$14,MATCH(MIN($B$2:$B$14),$B$2:$B$14,0),1)`

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: This looks like the correct answer if the numbers are sorted ascending so deserves an upvote. I might post another answer not assuming they are sorted.

Comment: Hi Tom, this seems to work however a non sorted version would be great since I don't know if the list will be sorted in all cases.  really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well what looks like a fairly simple question actually was quite tricky because you run into rounding errors when you compute the differences which can lead to a wrong answer. I ended up arbitrarily rounding the results to 10 decimal places before comparing them to get round this but it does not look an elegant formula:

```
=MIN(IF((ROUND(ABS(ROUND(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),0)-A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),10)=MIN(ROUND(ABS(ROUND(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),0)-A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),10))),A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Assumes there are no gaps in the data (which would throw out the Counta and also give a result of zero for the minimum difference).

**EDIT**

This is only an experiment to see if you get the right answer using decimal types

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub findClosestToInt()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, nRows As Long, nData As Long, nMins As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim data() As Variant, differences() As Variant, minData() As Variant
Dim minDiff As Variant, minValue As Variant, maxData As Variant


Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print ("LR=" & LastRow)
nRows = LastRow - 1


ReDim data(LastRow - 1)
ReDim differences(LastRow - 1)

' store data as decimal

nData = 0
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        nData = nData + 1
        data(nData) = CDec(sht.Cells(i, 1))
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve data(nData)
ReDim differences(nData)

Debug.Print ("nData=" & nData)

' find differences from nearest integer

For i = 1 To nData
    differences(i) = Abs(data(i) - Round(data(i), 0))
    Debug.Print (differences(i)) ' no rounding errors
Next i

minDiff = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(differences)

Debug.Print ("minDiff=" & minDiff)

ReDim minData(nData)

' find min of data where difference is equal to min difference

nMins = 0
For i = 1 To nData
    If differences(i) = minDiff Then
        nMins = nMins + 1
        minData(nMins) = data(i)
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve minData(nMins)

minValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(minData)

Debug.Print ("minValue=" & minValue)

End Sub
```

The result is 1.99 which is correct. If you just use (say) double instead, you get the wrong answer.

I think it is OK to use the worksheet function Min once you've worked out the differences.

It is straightforward to allow for blank cells in the data if required - the VBA approach does win all round I think.

Comment: Cheers! without further rounding, the second lot of data gave me 3.99, which is wrong.

Comment: In my opinion the best solution is a VBA code. Fast and clear

Comment: Yes, good idea. I guess you then have the option of using the Decimal data type which should avoid rounding errors.